# IntelliJ IDEA does not recognise specific database schema in Javascript/Typescript files

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, typescript, intellij-idea

At some point I was amazed when I managed to set the support of specific schema in my nodejs modules. Unfortunately, later IntelliJ IDEA decided to crash and I needed to remove my .idea folder, thus I lost all of my configurations. So, the problem is that when I write SQL queries *it does not find tables or functions* which exist in my database. I have it connected in the DB view and can run queries, but I want autocompletion also for SQL queries in Javascript/Typescript files.

So, the question: ***how to tell to Intellij IDEA that it understands SQL queries for specific database schema in Javascript/Typescript files***?

My tries:

1. I have found that there is [search_path environment variable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/schemas.html) which should do it:

> The search_path environment variable in PostgreSQL specifies the order
>   in which schemas are searched. For example, you set the value of
>   search_path to z,a,public, PostgreSQL will look for a value in the z
>   schema. If nothing was not found in the z schema, PostgreSQL looks for
>   the value in the a schema.

PostgreSQL is my case, thus I have tried to add the names of the schemas to search_path (that I have added to as a new property in Advanced tab for my database (maybe it is wrong place?)), but it didn't help.

2. I have verified that Settings -> Language Injections contain SQL in Javascript.
3. I have tried to Attach Session which was offered as a hint to the problem, but it didn't help.

So, where it could be set?

Comment: Configure [SQL Resolution Scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-sql-resolution-scopes.html) where map these files to the database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000323/andrey) mentioned in the comment, to resolve this, [SQL Resolution Scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-sql-resolution-scopes.html) must be configured. This configuration can be found from Settings => Languages & Frameworks => SQL Resolution Scopes.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this information will be able to help someone.

I had this problem in Intellij IDEA Database tab.

I got the solution doing :
Data Sources and Drivers -> YOUR_DATA_SOURCE -> Schemas -> Check "All databases"